# Locating a cell's position in google sheets using a string or an integer

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

This problem seems so simple but I've been searching/trying for several hours to find a solution. I basically have a large spreadsheet (3k rows of ISBN's) which each have a corresponding author, title, genre etc.

My plan was to make a function that allows me to simply produce a small UI, which takes in an Isbn and an amount, has a submit button (all done) and then finds that ISBN and increments a value in that row. The big stumbling block is being able to use the isbn which has been stored as a variable and finding the match in the table, as I simply cannot find some sort of "getValue()" function in google sheets.

I've seen several examples of people loading their entire data into an array and comparing the desired value to each individual entry, but that seems ridiculously inefficient and slow to me? Surely there must be a simple, efficient way that I'm just overlooking. All I'm after is a simple way of searching for a value, finding that value in the sheet and returning that row.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your assumption that *there must be a more efficient way to find an item in a spreadsheet* is not true. There is no "find" method in spreadsheet service but array iteration is fast and bulk data reading is also very fast so you shouldn't be annoyed with the speed parameter even for very long lists.

Here are 2 code snippets that find the row number of a string in column 1.

In the first one I transposed the array so that I could search in a single column in a simple array.

Both show the time it takes in milliseconds.

```
function testISBN1(){
  var time = new Date().getTime();
  var isbn = 'test1990'; // just as a test... create your own Ui to enter the value to search for
  Logger.log(findISBN(isbn)+'  in '+(new Date().getTime()-time)+' mSec');// view result... false if no occurrence (do something with that value)
}

function findISBN(isbn){
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');// select your sheet
  var data = sh.getDataRange().getValues(); // get all data at once
  var isbnColumn = transpose(data)[0];// if isbn is column 1 (it became row1 because of transpose
  for(var n in isbnColumn){
    if(isbnColumn[n] == isbn){ n++ ; return n }; // if found, increment to get the sheet row number
  }
  return false;// not found
}


function transpose(a) { // classical Array transpose JS function
  return Object.keys(a[0]).map(
    function (c) { return a.map(function (r) { return r[c]; }); }
  )
}
```

And the second one, without transpose takes about the same time to execute (about 230 mS in a 2000 rows sheet)

```
function testISBN2(){
  var time = new Date().getTime();
  var isbn = 'test1990'; // just as a test... create your own Ui to enter the value to search for
  Logger.log(findISBN2(isbn)+'  in '+(new Date().getTime()-time)+' mSec');// view result... false if no occurrence (do something with that value)
}

function findISBN2(isbn){
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');// select your sheet
  var data = sh.getDataRange().getValues(); // get all data at once
  for(var n in data){
    if(data[n][0] == isbn){ n++ ; return n }; // if found (in column 1), increment to get the sheet row number
  }
  return false;// not found
}
```

Below is the execution transcript that shows the time taken by every line of code. As you can see, the total execution time is mainly used to get the sheet and get its values.

[image]