# Locating all cell's positions in google sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

The problem is: I have big spreadsheet (more than 4500 rows) with a lot of data in the first column - for ex. with types of fruits, which are not unique, like this:

```
APPLE
BANANA
APRICOTS
APPLE
BLACKCURRANT
APPLE
BANANA
APRICOTS
etc.
```

What I need - locate each BANANA, to be able to put in cell beside some info, for ex. YES. I tried to loop solution from [Locating a cell's position in google sheets using a string or an integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25564616/locating-a-cells-position-in-google-sheets-using-a-string-or-an-integer) but for sure my code is wrong. I already spent a lot of hours to invent something, but still don't understand what I'm missing.

```
function test(){
  var dispatch = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("FRUITS"); 
  var find = dispatch.getRange("A:A").getValues();
  var name = "BANANA";

  var lastRow = dispatch.getLastRow();
  var n = 1;
  var temp = dispatch.getRange(n, 2).getValue();
  var i = 0;

  while (temp != ""){
    for(var n in find){
      if(find[n][0] === name){break}
    }
    n++;
    var n = n + i;
    dispatch.getRange(n, 2).setValue("YES");
    var temp = dispatch.getRange(n, 2).getValues();
    var find = dispatch.getRange(n, 2, lastRow).getValues();
    var i = n;
  } 
}
```

I will be very grateful for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code example is below:

```
function test(){
  var dispatch = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("FRUITS"); 
  var range = dispatch.getRange(1, 1, dispatch.getLastRow(), 2);
  var values = range.getValues();
  values.map(function(row) {
    if (row[0] == "BANANA")
      row[1] = "YES";
  });
  range.setValues(values);
}
```

[JS array `map()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) does the most part of work. We convert range values to JS array and back after mapping completes.

Comment: It is working - thank you so much! And thank you for shared link with the method - of course it will be good part of my education in JS :)